# View table of contents ( jQuery , ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want view  of contents from another site ...
Dont work my code (only jquery, ajax , javascript)

my code:

```js
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.varzesh3.com/table/min/Spain?cols=1110000011',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
        var data = jQuery(res.responseText).find('.table').text();
        jQuery('#test').html(data);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test"></table>
```

Comment: Cross-site requests are not allowed by browsers. Maybe, try a JSONP request.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ How is JSONP going to work when OP is trying to retrieve HTML? Also note that cross-domain requests are allowed by browsers so long as the receiving domain specifically enables them via CORS

Comment: @varzesht if you check the console you'll see this error: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`. This means that you cannot make cross-domain requests to this domain from JS as the response does not contain CORS headers. You will have to make the request from the server side instead. See the duplicate I marked for more information

Comment: Please teach a link or check an example.